How to use generalized_contact_forces in Drake MultibodyPlant
Drake's MultibodyPlant has an output port for generalized_contact_forces.  I want to use this port to see what contact forces are being applied to the gripper of my robot. However, the documentation does not mention what type of data is being sent through this port. Are there some resources that explain what a generalized contact force is, and how to consume the data coming from this port?

I agree that the documentation is lacking there.  My understanding (also by checking the code) is that the value is tau_contact which represents the contact forces (normal and friction) mapped to the generalized coordinates (via the contact Jacobian). It has the same size as plant.num_velocities.
